# How to change an empty string to a string from onclick in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, I am unable to change the playerInput to one of the following element even after clicking on the svg in HTML. When I console log, they return empty string, may I know how I could possibly fix this?

```
<html>
    <input type="image" src="images/rock.svg" class="rock" onclick ="playerClick()">
    <input type="image" src="images/scissor.svg" class="scissor" onclick ="playerClick()">
    <input type="image" src="images/paper.svg" class="paper" onclick ="playerClick()">

<script>
    let playerInput = "";
    
    function playerClick() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("rock")){
     playerInput === "Rock"
    } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("scissor")){
     playerInput === "Scissor"
    } else if (document.getElementsByClassName("paper")){
     playerInput === "Paper"
    } 
    return playerInput;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to set the value of playerInput you need to change playerInput === ...  to playerInput = ...  But probably your code will not work anyway because the if statement are wrong. What you want exactly do? How you call the function plyerClick()?

Answer (score 0):

This way you can `console.log` the clicked image.

```js
function playerClick(selection){
  console.log(selection)
}
```

```html
  <input type="image" src="images/rock.svg" class="rock" onclick ="playerClick('rock')">
  <input type="image" src="images/scissor.svg" class="scissor" onclick ="playerClick('scissor')">
  <input type="image" src="images/paper.svg" class="paper" onclick ="playerClick('paper')">
```

If you want to use and return the value based on the `class`, you could do it like this:

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', ()=> alert(input.classList)));
```

```html
<input type="image" src="images/rock.svg" class="rock">
<input type="image" src="images/scissor.svg" class="scissor">
<input type="image" src="images/paper.svg" class="paper">
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed your `<input` elements to `<img` elements - you don't need input elements to show an image and capture a click. In your `img` elements, you can pass a reference to the object itself using `this`. Then in your function, receive the element and use it to test it's classes, as below. Finally, to set values, use a single `=`

```
<html>
    <img src="images/rock.svg" class="rock" onclick ="playerClick(this)" />
    <img src="images/scissor.svg" class="scissor" onclick ="playerClick(this)" />
    <img src="images/paper.svg" class="paper" onclick ="playerClick(this)"/>

<script>
    let playerInput = "";
    
    function playerClick(el) {
    if (el.classList.contains("rock")){
     playerInput = "Rock"
    } else if (el.classList.contains("scissor")){
     playerInput = "Scissor"
    } else if (el.classList.contains("paper")){
     playerInput = "Paper"
    } 
    return playerInput;
    }
</script>
```